# How to read the data in the tsfile of Apache IoTDB when metadata is damaged?

Tags: metadata, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Since the data stored in Apache IoTDB is based on metadata structure, I wonder if the metatadata of Apache IoTDB is damaged, is there any way to read out the data in the tsfile of IoTDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tsfile API in Apache IoTDB to read and get the data information of metadata from tsfiles.